# Install a specific nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've just upgraded from 14.04 to 15.04 & want to solve a problem with Nvidia drivers I've had for a while. I'm currently running using Nouveau, but this causes screen scrambles when switching users, or accessing the dash. (Nouveau was OK under 14.04) 
My Nvidia drivers **were** fine under 14.04  using nvidia304.125, but caused problems when 304.128 came along. I couldn't manage to revert to 304.125, so ended up with Nouveau which was OK.
Having upgraded to 15.04 I find Nouveau to be a bit flaky, I've failed with later Nvidia drivers (up to 346) so would really like to be able to use the 304.125 version, however I am presented only with 304.128 from Nvidsia-current.
I have a Nvidia GeForce 6200 Turbocache card which I know works well with 304.125 Ubuntu 14.04 because I still have a boot option to that on a second hard disk which works faultlessly, so...
How do I install specifically Nvidia 304.125 drivers within Ubuntu 15.04??

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-version or use jockey (additional drivers) and specify the version or download the version you want from a ppa or install a version you want from the nvidia site. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that & using version 304 will only bring 304.128 not the 304.125 that I need - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer** :

As this very special **NVIDIA drivers version 304.125** is not available in the repositories and also not in any (not depreciated) Launchpad PPA you will have to install the NVIDIA drivers manually.

Before you install the drivers remove every NVIDIA related software and external repositories !

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mamarley/nvidia
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Download and install the drivers from NVIDIA website following the installation instructions.

When you have a 64 bit version of Ubuntu -> [NVIDIA LINUX X64 DISPLAY DRIVERS 304.125](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/80134/en-us)

Install instructions : [NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver README and Installation Guide](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.125/README/index.html)

When you have a 32 bit version of Ubuntu -> [NVIDIA LINUX X86 DISPLAY DRIVERS 304.125](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/80133/en-us)

Install instructions : [NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver README and Installation Guide](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/304.125/README/index.html)

Comment: I've just tried that thanks, but  the Additional Drivers show only as version 304.128 - no sign of 304.125? I've just noticed that whilst that PPA is active , I also have the PPA for  xorg-edgers still live - should I disable that PPA as well?

Comment: @JohnLloyd : I updated the answer with an alternative solution ! :)

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive answer, but reading those installation instructions has frightened the life out of me! 
Rather than undergo that torture, I'll look for a newer graphics card.
I do regard this episode & some previous hiccups with nvidia drivers as a real downside to Ubuntu - it's a real pain not to be able to roll back a failed driver easily. It took me ages to find what to do when presented with  a frozen system with a screen resembling the good old (not!) CPM days.

Comment: For future reference, is there an easy way of preventing a graphic driver update causing all this hassle once you have the proper driver working?

Comment: @JohnLloyd : Yes - when you are using "more modern" hardware it will be just as easy as opening "Software & Updates" to install the drivers with "one click" - updating the drivers using "Software Updater" are no hassle at all - so no frightening necessary ! :)

Comment: @JohnLloyd - By far the easiest solution to to purchase computers with LInux pre-installed, same as windows. Alternately purchase a linux compatible video card, they are not *that* expensive. If you choose to use incompatible hardware you will have a continuous fight (so quit complaining). Keep in mind, we are all volunteers and you should driect your complaints to Nvidia as you are using a closed source driver.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - Pull your neck in boyo! Where do you read a "complaint" here? Anyway, two points to respond to your observation: buy a new machine everytime I upgrade Ubuntu? What is this - Windows in the 1990's? Secondly - it was an Ubuntu upgrade (not a download from Nvidia) that started this problem & my old card was fine from Ubuntu 9 up until 14.04, so is hardly incompatible. Your point about volunteers, whilst valid, is the same for virtually all information forums, & please note I did thank both previous answerers to my problem.

Comment: @JohnLloyd But Ubuntu does not maintain the nvidia binary, so it is wrong of you to blame Ubuntu for your problems.